# Three button combination to open next scene

Tags: unity, c#

I have thirty (30) buttons in a trivia game, they are laid out in the following configuration with three rows:

```
( A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J)
( 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
(00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09)
```

Using these combinations of buttons and clicking one and only one from each row I have a thousand (1000) - three (3) button combinations. E.g.: A27 would be one combination of the thousand possibilities. These are not random combinations each opens a very specific scene.

What I am trying to do is create a C# script that when I click any of these three (3) button combinations it will open a new scene. Once that scene is open I’m okay because then have my own scripts attached to the single buttons in the new scene to continue to a further scene.

What I can’t figure out is the syntax, should I use `if` Statements such as -  `if (Btn_A)  &&  (Btn_1)  &&  (Btn_01)` then load scene such and such? Then do I attach the script to the canvas then to each of the three button combinations (A 1000 Scripts combinations)?

Comment: it is a bit unclear what you're asking. Do you mean that you got 1000 scenes? And then you want your script to open one of those scenes depending on which combination is pressed?

Comment: @Leggy7 **Edit:** I think he actually means he has 1000 scenes.

Comment: Yeah, 10^3 possible combinations, 10 buttons per row and three choices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not try to hardcode the combinations. Seems fairly straightforward to name your scenes A207, or F409, and so on. When the button combination is entered, simply load the scene with the name produced.

```
string button1 = selectedButtonA.text;
string button2 = selectedButtonB.text;
string button3 = selectedButtonC.text;
string name = button1 + button2 + button3;

SceneManager.LoadScene(name);
```

This code executes in a script attached to the canvas object or some kind of manager object. Each row of buttons has a script that sets the selected button values. i.e. the first row buttons, when selected, will assign themselves to `selectedButtonA` in the scene loading script.

Comment: Clever solution.

Comment: Thank you I will try this and I'm sure it will work for me.